# Как приравнять одну структуру другой в C#?

Tags: c#, структуры

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public string name;
}
MyStruct vasya;
vasya.name = "vasya";
Console.WriteLine(vasya.name);
MyStruct petya = vasya;
petya.name = "petya";
Console.WriteLine(vasya.name); // здесь я хочу увидеть "petya", но вижу "vasya"
```

Вся проблема как раз в том и состоит, что необходимо использовать структуры, а не классы.

Comment: Структуры всегда копируются сами, а не их ссылки, на то они и структуры, знаете ли...
Но можно использовать небезопасный код и указатели, если так уж хочется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как верно заметили в комментарии: при присвоении одного объекта структуры другому происходит копирование значений, но ссылки в итоге указывают на разные области памяти. Что мы и видим в коде: изменение одного объекта не влечет за собой изменение другого.
Как вариант, пришло в голову следующее решение:

```
internal interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

internal struct Person : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IPerson vasya = new Person {Name = "vasya"};
        IPerson petya = vasya;

        Console.WriteLine(vasya.Name);

        petya.Name = "petya";

        Console.WriteLine(vasya.Name);
    }
}
```

Это безусловно костыль и я бы не рекомендовал такого делать. Работает, как понятно из примера, только потому, что мы оперируем интерфейсами, а не структурами (ссылочными типами данных). Более того, объекты постоянно упаковываются\распаковываются (boxing\unboxing), что влечет потери производительности.

Comment: Спасибо за попытку. Вы подсказали мне чуууть менее костыльный способ. Но через всё ту же упаковку. Он позволяет орудовать структурами, не наследованными ни от какого интерфейса:

static void Main()
{
 System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
 Console.WriteLine(p);
 object obj = p;
 foo(ref obj);
 p = (System.Drawing.Point)obj;
 Console.WriteLine(p);
}
static void foo(ref object obj)
{
 System.Drawing.Point tmp = (System.Drawing.Point)obj;
 tmp.X = 100;
 obj = tmp;
}

Comment: капец форматирование слетело